# Hexagon/honeycomb buttons

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am looking for a way for creating hexagon/honeycomb shaped buttons in Xamarin Forms. Not only shall they have a honeycomb shape, but they should be arranged as honeycombs too.

```
 _
/ \_
\_/ \
/ \_/
\_/
```

Any ideas how this can be done? So far, I was thinking about giving [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp) a try, but I am afraid this will take weeks to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use images... If you use absolute layouts, this should be totally doable.